# Django form wizard dispatcher

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have a form that is two pages long. Although, the first page asks a basic question, and based on the answer it needs to redirect to one of three forms to be filled out, then submitted. I have created a diagram to help illustrate:
[image]

I am using django form wizard, but I don't know exactly how to structure my view in order to incorporate this type of logic.

Could someone help me get started with this? **Preferably showing some code that needs to be preformed in the django-form SessionWizardView.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either try overriding `get_form()` method to return intended form for 2nd step. Or add all 3 forms as step and skip not required steps with `condition_dict` and callable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to override get_form if you're solely depending on data from the previous form, you can use a condition_dict, mapping the form by the self defined ID on initializing the WizardView.

I don't like having too much going on in my urls.py for defining the WizardView, so I wrap the WizardView in a standard view function, and put the normal view function in the urls.py.

```
    def buy_cart_wizard_view_wrapper(request):

        con_dict = {FORM_ID_BILLING_ADDRESS_PICK: db_funcs.check_wizard_has_addresses_buy_cart,
                    FORM_ID_BILLING_ADDRESS: db_funcs.check_wizard_create_billing_pick_buy_cart,
                    FORM_ID_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_PICK: db_funcs.check_wizard_has_addresses_shipping_pick_buy_cart,
                    FORM_ID_SHIPPING_ADDRESS: db_funcs.check_wizard_create_shipping_pick_buy_cart,
                    FORM_ID_SAVED_BUSINESS_PAYMENT_PICK: db_funcs.check_wizard_has_payments_buy_cart,
                    FORM_ID_SAVED_BUSINESS_PAYMENT: db_funcs.check_wizard_create_payment_pick_buy_cart,
        }

        form_list = [(FORM_ID_BILLING_ADDRESS_PICK, accounts_forms.AddressPickerForm),
                 (FORM_ID_BILLING_ADDRESS, accounts_forms.BillingAddressForm),
                 (FORM_ID_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_PICK, accounts_forms.AddressPickerForm),
                 (FORM_ID_SHIPPING_ADDRESS, accounts_forms.AddressForm),
                 (FORM_ID_SAVED_BUSINESS_PAYMENT_PICK, accounts_forms.SavedBusinessPmtPickerForm),
                 (FORM_ID_SAVED_BUSINESS_PAYMENT, accounts_forms.SavedBusinessPmtBuyCartForm),
                 ]

        return BuyCartWizardView.as_view(form_list,condition_dict=con_dict, initial_dict=ini_dict)(request)
```

And then an example of a condition check on the previous form, '

```
def check_wizard_create_payment_pick_buy_cart(wizard):
    """
    Check if the previous form has an address selected
    """
    cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step(FORM_ID_SAVED_BUSINESS_PAYMENT_PICK) or {}
    create_new_payment_ind = cleaned_data.get(FORM_FIELD_NAME) or ''
    if create_new_payment_ind != '':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Returns True to show the form as the next step, False to skip the form and move to the form after that or finish (if out of forms).

Comment: This is EXTREMELY helpful! I'll be trying your approach out today